# I want to import a list in app inventor 2, so that i use its length. But how do i do this?

Tags: android, filenames, app-inventor

I am using an FTP-server and want to change the filename of the file we're uploaden to the length of the list + 1. The file gets his name at the last part of the picture, the part that is lightened up.

Does somebody know a solution to this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As I can see, you are trying to adjust my [postfile example](https://puravidaapps.com/postfile.php)...

The filename of the file to be uploaded is defined in the global variable `strFilename` before uploading in the `ImagePicker1.AfterPicking` event, you can change the filename to any name you like.

And if you want to store the filenames of the uploaded files in a list, you should learn [how to work with lists](http://www.appinventorblocks.com/appinventor-tutorials-tips/appinventor-lists). It also helps to [do the tutorials](http://explore.appinventor.mit.edu/ai2/tutorials) to learn the basics of App Inventor. To add an item in a list, just use the `add items to list` block, see also the [documentation](http://appinventor.mit.edu/explore/ai2/support/blocks/lists.html#additems).

[image]

> **add items to list**
>   Adds the given items to the end of the list. The difference between
>   this and append to list is that append to list takes the items to be
>   appended as a single list while add items to list takes the items as
>   individual arguments. This block is a mutator.